# Difficulty handling touch events with a UITableView

Tags: iphone

I am implementing a Google+ type iPhone application. The UI consists of a number of screen-sized panels, and the user can move through these panels horizontally by swiping left or right. I am not using a `UIScrollView` for this, but am instead implementing it as a series of `UIView`s on top of a master `UIView` - I override the `touches...` events for the `UIView`s and pass them on to the master `UIView` to handle repositioning the panels.

My code works perfectly as long as each panel is just an empty `UIView` (or if it only contains controls that don't pick up touch events, like a `UILabel`). The problem I'm facing is when I try to put a `UITableView` on one of the panels. Because the `UITableView` picks up the touch events, this is interfering with my own code that uses the touch events to slide the panels horizontally.

I have tried two approaches, neither of which is working perfectly:

**First approach:** I subclass `UITableView`, overriding the `touch...` events (`touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, and `touchesEnded`). In the overrides, I pass the events on to `self.nextResponder` and then to `super`. On my table, I also set `canCancelContentTouches = NO;`. This works somewhat - if I start swiping with a perfectly horizontal movement, the underlying panel containing the table view moves left and right. However, if I begin the process by swiping vertically, the table view begins scrolling up and down and no horizontal movement happens at all until I lift my finger. Also, if I begin swiping horizontally the left-right movement of the panel happens, but until I life my finger no vertical scrolling of the table view is possible (I'm trying to get a solution where vertical movement scrolls the table view and horizontal movement moves the underlying panel left-right). BTW, without the `canCancelContentTouches = NO;` call, the touch events stop coming altogether as soon as the table view is scrolled even a little bit.

**Second approach:** I subclass a `UIView`, set it's background color to transparent, and then place it over top of the view containing the `UITableView`. In this overlay subclass, I override the touch events and 1) pass them on to the underlying `UITableView` and then 2) pass the touch events on to the underlying `UIView` that handles the left-right swiping. With the approach, the left-right panel movement works perfectly. With the table view, unfortunately, the passed-through touch events allow me to click the table view and change the selected row (so I know the events are at least partially going through), but I can't scroll the table view up or down.

Any suggestions for how to do this correctly are welcome.