# Two finger UISwipeGestureRecognizer with UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I'm looking to add a gesture recognizer to UITableView that uses two finger up or down, like Twitterific has for toggling the status bar.

Here's my code

```
[self.tableView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
[self.tableView.panGestureRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUpGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleSwipeUp)];
[swipeUpGesture setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];
[swipeUpGesture setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp];
[swipeUpGesture setDelaysTouchesBegan:YES];
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:swipeUpGesture];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeDownGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleSwipeDown)];
[swipeDownGesture setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];
[swipeDownGesture setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown];
[swipeUpGesture setDelaysTouchesBegan:YES];
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:swipeDownGesture];
```

I'm calling this in viewDidLoad and doubleSwipeUp is not being called.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

First I would check to make sure that self.tableView.multipleTouchEnabled is set to YES.

If that doesn't help then maybe try setting swipeUpGesture.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;

Comment: I'm not familiar with twitterific. Is the 2 finger swipe suppose to occur on a cell or on the tableview as a whole? If it's a cell then you would need to be adding the gesture recognizer in the cellForRowAtIndexPath code

Comment: It's on the tableView as a whole.

Comment: Ok lets see what else there is to try. How about setting the tableviews panGestureRecognizer's maximumNumberOfTouches = 1?

Comment: Hmm sorry I'm out of ideas then. You could potentially try one of the methods listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854728/difficulty-handling-touch-events-with-a-uitableview